# Comparing parseInt to NaN in Actionscript 3

Tags: actionscript-3, nan, parseint

The AS3 documentation states that if you pass in a string to `parseInt` that is not a number it will return `NaN`. However, when I try to compare to `NaN` the compiler gives me the following error:

```
Warning: 1098: Illogical comparison with NaN. This statement always evaluates to false.
```

The statement is actually true. Comparing to NaN will always return `false`. How can I compare to NaN to detect if what was parsed was NaN?

```
if( parseInt("test") == NaN )
{
   // do something (never gets here)
}
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Compare with `isNaN()` function.

Comment: Slap forehead. Of course. I now remember I had the same problem in AS2 years ago. Why isn't the parseInt documentation referring to the isNaN function?

Answer (score 9):

Use [isNaN()](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/package.html#isNaN%28%29) global function

```
if(isNaN(parseInt("test")))
{
   // do something 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Everyone is correct, use the `isNaN()` function:

http://www.adobe.com/livedocs/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/package.html#isNaN()

I've never really liked this method.  I prefer to test for positives.

Interestingly though, if a Number is NaN then it will *not* equate to itself:

```
var parsed_int:Number = parseInt("test");
if(parsed_int != parsed_int)
  trace("NaN");
```

Therefor, testing if the Number equates to itself should give you the positive:

```
var parsed_int:Number = parseInt("123");
if(parsed_int == parsed_int)
  trace("Number");
```

It's not very clear what your intentions are when reading the code, so be sure to comment it if you use it.

Or you could add a top-level function:

```
function isNumber(num:Number):Boolean{
  return num == num;
}
```

And a note for the optimisation nuts out there.  The inline version is fastest.

Just for reference: http://www.adobe.com/livedocs/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/package.html#parseInt()

Comment: The `isNaN` function is self-documenting however. Without a comment explaining why you are comparing a value against itself it just looks like a redundant piece of code.

Comment: Yes, but I always find it interesting to know how something works.  Plus if you're looking to only do something if parseInt returns a Number the you end up with code like if(!isNaN(parseInt("test"))). Is not not a number?  It's just ugly in my opinion.

Comment: `NaN` is not a single number, rather a range of [numbers of certain format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754-1985#NaN). What's more, ECMA spec [expressly forbids you](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.9.3) to use NaNs in comparisons: the result is always false.